# How can I get TFS 2013 to detect files deleted in the file system?

Tags: version-control, tfs

When I delete a file in the file system, TFS 2013 will correctly show it as still being in version control, but the file will not show as pending delete, and committing changes does not remove the file from the server. If I go to Source Code Explorer, the deleted file shows up as being on the server, but if I try to delete it, I get an error saying `The item could not be found in your workspace`, which is also correct, but I need to delete the file and I can't find any way to do it. I really do NOT want to have to download each file and manually delete it.

So, how can I get TFS to detect files that are no longer on the local file system and remove them from the server?

Note, my workspace is local, not server. Many sources say that TFS should detect local deletes in a local workspace, but this does not seem to be true, at least, it's not what I'm seeing.

Update: I know that my workspace is local because here's the TFS Workspaces window:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the changes are not being detected then your workspace is currently configured as a Server Workspace and not a Local Workspace.

If you edit your workspace, click Advanced, and switch the workspace type to Local.

Note: You can check the configuration by looking for the hidden $tf folder in the root of your workspace...

Comment: I added a screenshot to show that my workspace is in fact local, unless this dialog doesn't mean what I think it means. I found the hidden $tf folder but it's just got a bunch of binary files in it. How would I check the configuration with this folder?

Comment: You dont, if its there you have a Local workspace and it will auto detect changes. The ony reasons not is a) its broken and you need to delete it and create a new one or b) you are hitting a performance 100k file limit. You should really have no more than 30k files in a local workspace. If you need moew then switch to a Server Workspace.

Comment: I noticed that you have crap tones of mapped paths? I normally only see one maybe two maped paths in a workspace. Why so many?

Comment: The workspace is local, so why doesn't it detect deletes? I don't know about crap tones, but those are there because there are a number of old version control trees that we should probably purge but haven't gotten around to.

Comment: Have you verified the number of files if you workspace? If its more than 25k (or 80k on SSD) you cant use Local workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use /deletes with the tfs power tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/11/16/power-toy-tfpt-exe.aspx#Online